# Hide title of a Bootstrap NavBar

Tags: css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I have done a Bootstrap NavBar and I want that when screen size would be `sm`, `md` or `lg` this item: `<a class="navbar-brand" href="http://www.upct.es/"><span id="idTextoLogotipo">UPCT</span></a>` would be hidden and `text-left` my menuItems. And when screen size would be `xs` this `<a href...` re-appear.

My NavBar code is:

```
        <nav id="idNavMenu" class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">

            {/*<a class="navbar-brand" href="/inicio"><img id="idFotoLogotipo" width="200px" src="./assets/images/cabecera_CE.jpg"/></a>*/}

            <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://www.upct.es/"><span id="idTextoLogotipo">UPCT</span></a>

            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Menú</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <MenuNavItem to='/alumno/inicio' index={true}>Inicio</MenuNavItem>
                    <MenuNavItem to='/alumno/nueva_incidencia'>Nueva Incidencia</MenuNavItem>
                    <MenuNavItem to='/alumno/mis_incidencias'>Mis Incidencias</MenuNavItem>
                </ul>

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <MenuNavItem to=''><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span> Salir</MenuNavItem>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </nav>
```

How could I do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap has a class called `visible-xs-block` which makes elements only visible on `xs`. Attach that to the `<a>` tag.

```
<a class="navbar-brand visible-xs-block" href="http://www.upct.es/"><span id="idTextoLogotipo">UPCT</span></a>
```

Now the `navbar-brand` will only be seen on widths corresponding to `xs` (<768px)

Comment: Cool! Thank you. But now, I continue having the other problem: When it is hidden, there is a white space at left, how could I make it dissapeared?

Comment: Add a `@media-query` for `max-width:768px` (corresponding to `xs`) and apply a `margin-left` equal to some negative value to `.navbar-header`. One mistake though I am seeing in your code is that the `.navbar-brand` should be inside the `.navbar-header` not outside like you are doing now according to standard Bootstrap considerations. Try that first. It should solve your problem.